# how to get location using C# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gps

I want to develop C# base windows application

In this application i want to display current location using GPS and without GPS

How can i get my current location from GPS in C# windows application

I have two case

Case I: First my GPS is ON than i get location from GPS and display it

Case II: If GPS is OFF than i have two display near by location

But i don't know how to use GPS in C# windows application and how to get current latitude and longitude form GPS and without GPS

Comment: Do you have any code ?
Have you try this link ? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/ReadGPS09052007011539AM/ReadGPS.aspx

Comment: no i do not have any code .... i read given article but still i am confuse because i have to attach GPS device? and how can i get current location ?

Comment: without GPS device is it possible?